# Why does libreoffice soffice.bin process CONSTANTLY RECEIVE internet bandwidth ? Malware ? Virus ? What?

Tags: networking, security, libreoffice, malware, bandwidth

Why does **libreoffice soffice.bin process CONSTANTLY RECEIVE** internet **traffic** ?
This is according to  BOTH NetHogs and Gnome System Monitor.

I was curious about KB/sec internet IO numbers that constantly appear in Gnome System Monitor, so  I starting using NetHogs version 0.8.1  to track down the Bandwidth usage *per process*. And I see the bandwidth total is the same in NetHogs as Gnome System Monitor.

So why does NetHogs show the individual /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin process RECEIVE INTERNET traffic constantly as per RECEIVED=10.257 KB/sec AND SENT=0.000  ?

If this is somehow expected behavior, how can I turn it down or off ?

Comment: Look under LibreOffice Tools > Options for anything that could possibly need the internet and turn it off?

Comment: Why are you using so many caps?

Comment: Unwanted IO continues for LibreOffice version xenial10  

So far the Steps to stop the mystery IO:  

#1) Upgraded libreoffice xenial3 version to xenial10   
Net result: No change soffice.bin still receiving 10 KB/s per nethogs AND gnome system monitor    

#2) Configured firewall rules to prevent IO all Ports all Protocols etc.   
Net result: No change soffice.bin still receiving 10 KB/s per nethogs AND gnome system monitor    

What other suggestions to stop this LibreOffice Mystery IO ?

Comment: Thx , I think I resolved the issue >>  

ONLY this worked to fix Linux malware botnet dubbed IptabLes and IptabLex  
   https://kerneltalks.com/virtualization/how-to-reset-iptables-to-default-settings/  

Step 2 : Delete all existing rules.
Using below set of commands, delete your currently configured rules from iptables.
( via sudo -i )
# iptables -F

Are mysterious programs in nethogs listing malware ?
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91055/how-to-tell-if-mysterious-programs-in-nethogs-listing-are-malware

Use netstat to NAME the calling Program 
# netstat -tapec